# "provided by" vs "provided with"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> The following default options are **provided by** the plugin.

or

> The following default options are **provided with** the plugin.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The first one implies that the options are already there, but that the defaults are only set the way they are because of the plugin. This is not impossible, but rather unusual; an example would be a Firefox network-tweaking addon that changes built-in configuration to (attempt to) improve performance.

The second is much more likely; it implies that the plugin includes certain options of its own and states that those are set to defaults that the plugin also determines. This would be the case whenever a plugin is configurable in its own right.